# Desktop Disapeared

Tags: 12.04, unity, plugins, .desktop

I disabled the unity plug-in, and now all I can see on my desktop is my wallpaper. I am using ubuntu 12.04 lts. Is there anyway to fix this? I just wanted to be able to customize my desktop some, and unity would not let me do it. Now my desktop is really customized cause all I have is my  wallpaper now...lol. Please help, and Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the terminal prompt (ie Ctrl + Alt + F1) and login.
Then enter:
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace

And it should restart unity. Then Ctrl + Alt + F7 to go back to your desktop.

If you're not satisfied with unity, you should try another desktop environment like gnome, cinnamon, mate, xfce, lxde... plenty to chose from.

To customize unity a bit, you can install ubuntu tweaks:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

or unity tweak tools
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

Have fun,

Answer (score 1):

The Unity plugin (for compiz) is what gives you the menu bar across the top and the launcher bar across the left.  If you disable it, all you'll have is the desktop.

[This site gives instructions for resetting your compiz settings in order to restore Unity](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04).

Excerpt:

> Install dconf-tools:
>
> Open a Terminal and run the following command to reset animations,
>   workspaces, launcher size, etc:
>
> ```
> dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
> ```

In order to do the above you will have to be able to switch to a terminal prompt (ie <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and log in as you if necessary (note the dconf command won't work when running sudo or logged in as root).

As to how to better customise your desktop, that's a whole other question.  Unity doesn't give you many options though.